# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: database, mamp, magento-2.0.7

i am using MAMP on Mac OSX Yasmite 10.10.5 and getting this error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

[image]

I have created database and name it magento.

[image]

[image]

Don't know where is the problem + there is no local.xml in magento/app/etc instead di.xml is available. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Your server host is localhost:8889

So on the Database Server host try to give localhost:8889 instead of on localhost.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 4):

Solved! i was missing the password and it was 'root' check in your phpmyadmin. Then i was asked for the mysql update because magento require 5.6 or above so this link helped me.

http://blog-en.mamp.info/2015/07/how-to-use-mysql-5-6-with-mamp-and-mamp.html

until step 2 you will be fine with magento.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue with Magento 2.0.7 installation.I was using *root* user without password so I got this issue.

After assigning a password to the *root* user(Do not forget to restart mysql server) and retrying to install solved the issue.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to restart MySQL after changing a password.

Comment: @RobbieAverill You may be right but in my case. I was able to proceed after restart only.